# Read CSV file as a dictionary containing first row as headers (keys)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a CSV file which contains a number of columns and dump the array into a dictionary. First row would be a key of dictionary, and the rest of the rows are list (values of key). I tried the following but I have loads of columns which may vary.

```
reader = csv.reader(open('CSV/Logger_data.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for key,value in reader:
    d[key] = value
```

DictReader seems to work but when I print through iterating but how can I store the data in a dictionary `reader`. This is what I tried so far:

```
with open ('CSV/Logger_data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row["DateTime"], row["Column1"])
```

Comment: No I looked at this thread, this contains first column as keys. But I have first row as keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

def get_mulList(*args):
    return map(list,zip(*args))

csv_data = open('logger_data.csv','r')
data = list(csv.reader(csv_data))
ind_dict = dict(zip(data[0],get_mulList(*data[1:])))    
print ind_dict
```

if your CSV is like this,

```
'DateTime'  'Column1'
 1-2-2012    a
 2-3-2013    b
 3-4-2014    c
```

from the above script you will get output like this,

```
{ 
  'DateTime':['1-2-2012','2-3-2013','3-4-2014'],
  'Column1':['a','b','c']
}
```

Comment: Yes I can get this output, but I want `{'Column1':['a','b','c'], 'DateTime':[1-2-2012, 2-3-2013, 3-4-2014]}`

Comment: I made changes based on your needs.. check now, it reduce bunch of loopings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import csv

d={}
with open("logger_data.csv","r") as csvf:
    content = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
    for row in content:
        if not row[0] in d:
            d[row[0]]=[]
        for value in row[1:]:
            d[row[0]].append(value);
```

For the csv file "logger_data.csv" looking like this:

> ab;123;234;345
>
> ce;1;2;3;4
>
> ll;99;12;123;4;5

Output:

```
{'ab': ['123', '234', '345'],
 'ce': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 'll': ['99', '12', '123', '4', '5']}
```

Comment: Thanks but my first row of CSV is `ab; ce; ll`. But you understood me what output i'm after!